# Does Word still change line and page breaking with a different printer?

Tags: microsoft-word

In ye olde days it was known that Word [changed the page layout if a different (default?) printer was selected](http://ask-leo.com/why_does_my_microsoft_word_document_display_differently_on_different_computers.html) since it somehow got the metrics from the printer and shifted words and letters around to accommodate for ... *um* ... something.

Now that we have a new file format and so, does anyone know the above to still be true? I couldn't discern a difference but my selection of printers here is pretty much limited to non-printers like OneNote, XPS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No: a Word document printed on one printer has **the exact same line and page breaks** as when printed on another printer.

Except:

- if you change the page layout (margins, paper size, etc.)
- if the two printers have different paper sizes
- if the two printers don't support the fonts you are using (in which case they might substitute with other fonts which may render differently)

I guess by *"ye olde days"* you mean pre-1995 when Windows and printers weren't really WYSIWYG.

Comment: No, "ye olde days" is still semi-recent (well, probably still recfent, give how many people still use an OS from that age); I added a link in my question that describes the problem. Also Word for DOS *was* WYSIWYG, although the default text mode view was more a WYSIWYM, indeed.

Comment: In the linked article, Leo more or less states the same three exceptions that I mentioned. I haven't seen this behaviour for many years myself, but then again I rarely switch between printers on the same computer, and I rarely compare the printed layout with the layout in a PDF. So I'm not denying that layout changes might still happen. I just don't notice.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's still the same as different printers have different print margins (how much of the page they can print on) and you will always end up with a little bit of shuffling and tweaking as a result to accommodate the different capabilities of a printer.

What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Curiosity, nothing more.